# How to retrieve hstore string type of array values into hash in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got below value in my hstore column `widget_locations`:

```
"left_area2"=>"{\"youtube\"=>{:youtube_id=>\"aasdsadsa\", :from=>\"100\", :to=>\"200\"}}"
```

This is saved using:

```
@webcast.create(:widget_locations => {:left_area2 => {:youtube => {:youtube_id => "aasdsadsa", :from => "100", :to => "200"}}})
```

I tried retrieving by

```
@webcast.left_area2
```

this is now returning

```
"{\"youtube\"=>{:youtube_id=>\"aasdsadsa\", :from=>\"100\", :to=>\"200\"}}"
```

Is there a way to change this into Rails array?

Comment: what about this `you_string.gsub('\\', '').gsub(/{+/, '[').gsub(/}/, ']').scan(/(\w+)/)` i have this output `[["youtube"], ["youtube_id"], ["aasdsadsa"], ["from"], ["100"], ["to"], ["200"]]`

Comment: @Monk_Code how do I get nested arrays from there though?

Comment: i don't understand you. (( look some [example](https://gist.github.com/fishbullet/220c5b0efd4267bee96f) where i try convert to hash you string.

Comment: @Monk_Code I'm getting `#<NoMethodError: undefined method `first' for #<Hash:0x19d47997>>` on the last line

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `Webcast` model, I'm guessing that you haven't used `serialize` on `widget_locations` as an hstore column should return a `Hash`.

Add `serialize :widget_locations, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore` to the top of your model and restart your server - that should at least return an object (e.g. `Hash`) rather than a string.

Comment: i thinking `rails` serialize `hstore` by default.

Comment: That's not been my experience.  Maybe in Rails 4 it's different, but in Rails 3 that's not the case.

Comment: i use `hstore` in `Rails 4` and my hash serialize by default. But my hash not be nested.